# Export Release Build is not working in Adobe Flash Builder, It does nothing on Finish button

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

In Flashbulider 4.7 I have project in actionscript3 for mobile application everything works fine like running it in debug and without debugging.
The problem is that I can't create air file or apk because Export Release Build has stopped working. It is suppose to return to main screen after clicking the finish button but it stays there without showing anything in error log.
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Flex Compiler:** Apache Flex 4.16.1 FP31.0 AIR31.0 en_US

In MobileEPOD-app.xml , I have specified version 33.1, otherwise it gives error that it expects more than 33

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/33.1">
```

I am willing to provide more information. Thank you for getting along

Comment: Add an `UncaughtErrorEvent Handler` like `loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);`, make it write to a file or show on-screen text for error, and see if it triggers